# Script for saving large no of entries in mongodb

Tags: grails-orm, mongodb-java

I have a mongodb database server.I want to get it fill up with large number of entries in a particular collection let say a collection named "user".
I want to know if there would be a script for saving large no of randomly created entries in my mongodb database from linux terminal or a Java code for the same.
I have a script that creates 10,000 entries in "user" collection:

```
> for(i=0;i<10000;i++){db.user.insert({username:'ashok'+i,password:'123'});}
```

This query creates the user names as ashok1 , ashok2 ,....
I want a script that could create random user names.
It could be better if I could get this done in grails.

Comment: Why don't you generate a random string using alphabets and use that as username?

Comment: You could use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-a-string-of-5-random-characters-in-javascript) and make a script that runs on mongodb.

Comment: I solved my problem using this code for grails    User user = new User(username: createRandomString() , password: createRandomString() , dateCreated:date)
 
/**
*It will create random string of length between 6 to 12 charaters
*/
def createRandomString()
{
 String charset = (('A'..'Z') + ('a'..'z') + ('0'..'9')).join()
 int length = 6 + new Random().nextInt(7)
 String randomString = RandomStringUtils.random(length, charset.toCharArray())
 return randomString
}